# How to call a function, once a prop is updated in a child component. Vue3 composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a todo list, which is generated from a for loop. Each `todo` is passed as a prop to a `<singleTodo />` child component. Once i delete a `todo` from the `<SingleTodo/>` component, how can i refresh the page(meaning: call the `getTodos` function). Using `onUpdated` lifecycle hook works, but the problem is that once i delete a single `todo`, there is an unstoppable GET loop to the REST API. Any thoughts?

**List Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <CreateTodo />
    <hr />

    <div class="TodoContainer">
      <SingleTodo
        v-for="todo in todos"
        v-bind:key="todo.id"
        :todo="todo"
        class="TodoComponent"
      />
    </div>
    <hr />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CreateTodo from "./CreateTodo";
import SingleTodo from "./SingleTodo";
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";

//
export default {
  components: {
    CreateTodo,
    SingleTodo,
  },

  props: {
    todo: Object,
  },

  setup() {
    const API_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todo-list/";
    const todos = ref([]);

    async function getTodos() {
      const response = await fetch(API_URL);
      const json = await response.json();
      todos.value = json;
    }


    onMounted(() => {
      getTodos();
    });

    // onUpdated(() => {
    //   getTodos();
    // });

    return {
      todos,
      getTodos,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**child component, SingleTodo.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ todo.id }}{{ todo.completion }}{{ todo.todo }}
    <button @click="removeTodo(todo.id)">delete</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import { getTodos } from "./TodoHooks.js";
import { getCookie } from "./TodoHooks.js";

export default {
  props: {
    todo: Object,
  },

  setup() {
    const API_DELETE = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todo-delete";
    const csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");

    //

    async function removeTodo(id) {
      var csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");
      fetch(`${API_DELETE}/${id}/`, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
          "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
        },
      }).then((response) => {
        // NEEDED TO UPDATE AUTOMATICALLY.
        // getTodos();
        return response;
      });
    }

    return {
      removeTodo,
      csrftoken,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to emit an event to the parent component to refresh the list, add `emits` option like :

```
props: {
    todo: Object,
  },
  emits:['refresh'],
....
```

then inside the `then` callback emit the `refresh` event :

```
 }).then((response) => {
        emit('refresh')
```

but before you should destruct the `emit` property from context in setup parameters `setup(_,{emit}) {`

full code :

```
<script>
// import { getTodos } from "./TodoHooks.js";
import { getCookie } from "./TodoHooks.js";

export default {
  props: {
    todo: Object,
  },
  emits:['refresh'],
  setup(_,{emit}) {
    const API_DELETE = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todo-delete";
    const csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");

    //

    async function removeTodo(id) {
      var csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");
      fetch(`${API_DELETE}/${id}/`, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
          "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
        },
      }).then((response) => {
        emit('refresh')
        return response;
      });
    }

    return {
      removeTodo,
      csrftoken,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

in parent component :

```
 <SingleTodo
        v-for="todo in todos"
        v-bind:key="todo.id"
        :todo="todo"
        class="TodoComponent"
        @refresh="getTodos"

      />
```